# Sum absolute values of one column using a groupby() of another column

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have the following toy DataFrame named `df`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'foo' : ['red', 'red', 'red', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'green', 'green', 'green'], 
                     'bar'  : [10, -5, 7, 14, 20, 3, 40, -100, 75]})

foo    bar   
red     10
red     -5
red     7
blue    14
blue    -20
blue    3 
green   40
green   -100
green   75
```

I would like to sum the **absolute values** of the `bar` column using a `groupby()` of the `foo` column.  Here is my attempt:

```
df['baz'] = df.groupby('foo').bar.apply(lambda x: x.abs().sum())
```

I would expect to see the following:

```
foo    bar     baz
red     10     22
red     -5     22
red     7      22
blue    14     37
blue    -20    37
blue    3      37
green   40     215
green   -100   215
green   75     215
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting `NaN` in the newly created `baz` column.

Why is this approach resulting in `NaN` values?  Separately (and notwithstanding the bug in my code), is there a more elegant (i.e. more Pythonic) way to do this?

Comment: Cannot currently test; `df['baz'] = df.groupby('bar').abs().sum().reset_index()`. Probably wishful thinking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with

```
df['baz'] = df.bar.abs().groupby(df['foo']).transform('sum')
```

Answer (score 0):

`pandas` aligns on `index` automatically, so your code does not work because the `index` of your `groupby` result is different than the index of your original dataframe. Consequently, it returns `nan`.

Having said that, you can set the index to be the 'foo' column, using `set_index()`, and retry your code:

```
df.set_index('foo',inplace=True)
df['baz'] = df.groupby('foo').bar.apply(lambda x: x.abs().sum())

print(df)

       bar  baz
foo            
red     10   22
red     -5   22
red      7   22
blue    14   37
blue    20   37
blue     3   37
green   40  215
green -100  215
green   75  215
```

---

A more pythonic way, as you say I think would be to use [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html), instead of setting the `index` and distort your original dataframe. Therefore, my recommendation would be keep your dataframe as it is, and change your code to:

```
df['baz'] = df.groupby('foo').bar.transform(lambda x: x.abs().sum())

print(df)

     foo  bar  baz
0    red   10   22
1    red   -5   22
2    red    7   22
3   blue   14   37
4   blue   20   37
5   blue    3   37
6  green   40  215
7  green -100  215
8  green   75  215
```

Comment: Is it really necessary to use `apply` for this? If it's for the sake of `abs()` it's probably still cheaper to make a temp column if the df is big enough

Comment: The df is not large (~5000 rows).

Comment: Agree with @roganjosh, if you can avoid ```apply``` it's better to avoid it. The key take away I believe here is to use ```transform``` as it is well suited for this type of operations. If speed and efficiency is very important for you, I think Beny's answer is spot on. My intention was to elaborate a bit.